# Using argparse to use a function at a specific point in the code?

Tags: python, function, argparse

If I try to run the argparse commands in terminal the function will run first and then the rest of the code. But I want to make it so the function will run at the very end of the code or at a specific point in the code. I tried making everything into functions, but that led to other problems.

```
filename = 'report_list.csv'

SPREADSHEET_ID = 'spreadsheet id here'
RANGE_NAME = "Baselines!A1:F200"

def Export_Data_To_Sheets():


    store = file.Storage('credentials.json')
    creds = store.get()
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', scopes)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    service = build('sheets', 'v4', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

    response_date = service.spreadsheets().values().update(
        spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID,
        valueInputOption='RAW',
        range=RANGE_NAME,
        body=dict(
            majorDimension='ROWS',
            values=df.T.reset_index().T.values.tolist())
    ).execute()
    print('Sheet successfully Updated')

global args

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--file', '-f', type=argparse.FileType('r'))
    parser.add_argument('--name', '-n')
    parser_sheets = parser.add_argument('--sheets', type=Export_Data_To_Sheets(), 
    action="store")
    args = parser.parse_args()

global baseline_dict
if args.file is not None:
    try:
        baseline_dict = json.load(args.file)
        args.file.close()
    except:
        print("JSON Baseline File {}: Unable to LOAD")

if args.name is not None:
    with open(args.name) as f:
        #print(json.load(f))
        #baseline_dict = f
        try:
            baseline_dict = json.load(f)
        except:
            print("JSON Baseline File {}: Unable to LOAD")

results_dict = baseline_dict["results"]
#Turns the new dictionary into a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(results_dict)

#Establishes first column and then individually makes the other columns
df.columns = ['hashed_secret']
df['is_verified'] = ''
df['line_number'] = ''
df['type'] = ''
#Breaks up Dictionary to appropriate columns
df = df['hashed_secret'].apply(pd.Series)

#Drops extra rows with same secret
df.drop_duplicates(subset='hashed_secret', keep='first', inplace=True)
```

I also tried putting the "if **name** == '**main**':" statement at the end of the code. Then tried putting the rest of the code(if args.file is not None:) before the function.
Which will return this. I even tried making args a global variable.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./Json_DetectSecrets.py", line 22, in <module>
if args.file is not None:
NameError: name 'args' is not defined
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! I'm not sure what you're trying to ask here. You may want to read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help others help you.  By the way, your `global args` is doing nothing here. `args` is already a global variable if `__name__ == '__main__'`.

Comment: Normal practice is to define functions (and import modules), and then put actual script execution code at the end in the `if __name__` block.  `parse_args` should be run from that block (even if embedded in a function).  `argparse` is primarily a parsing tool (understanding user input), not a code execution tool.